# Display data fetched from several rows on crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

how can I display data fetched from several rows on a crystal report. Im using vb.net. So far i can just display data fetched from only one row. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle of Reporting is to pass some datasource to your report, and on the design, link field with those datasource.
I don't use Crystal Report but the Report viewer from microsoft.
If you want i could explain the bases to you.

Julien